# Text Editor Anywhere not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, text-editors

I've been using http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere for ages.
But it broke on Windows 10 (10.0.18362.418).

I’ve set the shortcut shift-win-A to invoke it. Using this shortcut displays the list of configured editors, but then neither is executed. No error message is displayed.

I’ve configured these editors. Both run ok from the command line:

```
c:\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe "%1"
c:\totalcmd\tools\akelpad\notepad.exe "%1"
```

Comment: That is a very old product. Latest version is for Windows 7. Windows 10 changes have likely rendered it not compliant anymore.

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative that DOES save the text area to a tmp file before invoking the editor?

Comment: I use UltraEdit (best editor I have come across) but I don't think you can invoke it anywhere on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Triple shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> seem broken indeed. However, <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> works just fine.

The trouble is that <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> is a Windows 10 shortcut for the Action Centre. This is made worse by the fact that the [Text Editor Anywhere website](https://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere) still suggests <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> as the shortcut. I'm assuming you're aware of this conflict, and it's the reason you're trying to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> instead.

### Option 1: disable <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

If you don't use <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to open the Windows 10 Action Centre, you can disable it, so you can use it as the Text Editor Anywhere shortcut:

1. in the registry, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
2. create a new string value called `DisabledHotkeys`
3. set its value to "A"
4. restart the `explorer` process

(This is described [here](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-disable-any-specific-win-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows) but the registry path in that page seems wrong.)

### Option 2: disable all the <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>*</kbd> hotkeys

If you're so inclined, you can disable all the <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>*</kbd> hotkeys. This can be done [in two ways](https://www.isumsoft.com/it/disable-win-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10/). However, some of these shortcuts are very useful (<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to lock, <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to run a command, <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to start Explorer; see the full list [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)) so this doesn't really seem viable.

### Option 3: use another two-key shortcut

You could try to go with something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. This works just fine. However, many <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>*</kbd> combinations are already used (and useful) both by Windows and by apps. You may have an app where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> is indispensable (for me, that's [*vim*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#CTRL-E) and the equivalent shortcut in Vimium).

Comment: hi @sferencik! As I wrote "displays the list of configured editors, but then neither is executed". Have you tried your solution with Text Editor Anywhere?

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev, yes, I had your problem for ages. Basically stopped using TEA because of it. The list of editors would display and I could *click* to pick one of them (but not arrow-down and Enter) but having to use the mouse for this beat the purpose of course. But switching from Ctrl-Win-A to Win-A fixed this. Have you tried Win-A specifically?